# ng-model inside ngSwitch doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, json, ng-switch

I have form that sends calculated value in JSON format to server.
But I cannot understand why only ng-model that is inside ngSwitch doesn't sends in JSON array.
I supposed that ng-model should work within ngSwitch using $parent.
But it seems that angular still need something more.

Here is my form

```
    <form ng-app="SaunaDoorCalc" ng-controller="SaunaDoorCalcController" class="calculator" name="calculator">

....
<tr><td>Result</td> 
    <td ng-switch-default ng-model="$parent.doorsize">@{{selectedSizeSwitch}}, @{{selectedStandardSize.label}}</td>
    <td ng-switch-when="non-standard" ng-model="$parent.doorsize">@{{selectedSizeSwitch}}, @{{DoorSizeB}}x@{{DoorSizeH}}</td>   
    <td ng-switch-default ng-model="$parent.baseprice">@{{selectedStandardSize.price}}</td>
    <td ng-switch-when="non-standard" ng-model="$parent.baseprice">@{{DoorSizeB*DoorSizeH*5000/1000000}}
    </td>
</tr>

....

</form>
```

and my script

```
angular
  .module('SaunaDoorCalc',[])
    .controller('SaunaDoorCalcController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.outerScope = {};
    $scope.formData = {};

    .....

    $scope.submit = function(isValid) {
      if (isValid) {
          $http.post($scope.url, 
            {
              "calcname": "saunadoor", 
              "doorsize": $scope.doorsize, 
              "baseprice": $scope.baseprice, 
              "glass": $scope.selectedGlass, 
              "korobka": $scope.selectedKorobka, 
              "petli": $scope.selectedPetli, 
              "dekor": $scope.selectedDekor, 
              "dostavka": $scope.selectedDostavka,
              "montazh": $scope.montazh, 
              "name": $scope.name, 
              "tel": $scope.tel, 
              "email": $scope.email, 
              "msg": $scope.msg, 
            }).
                        success(function(data, status) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $scope.status = status;
                            $scope.data = data;
                            $scope.result = data; 
                        });
              $scope.name = null;
              $scope.tel = null;
              $scope.email = null;
              $scope.msg = null;
              $scope.DoorSizeB = null;
              $scope.DoorSizeH = null;
              $scope.calculator.$setPristine();
              $scope.message = 'Заказ отправлен. В ближайшее время мы с вами свяжемся.'; 

            }else{
              $scope.message = 'Заполните обязательные поля формы!'; 
            }

        }

  });
```

Answer (score 3):

`ng-model` doesnt bind to `td` elements you should use `ng-bind` instead

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

> The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive.

Comment: doing like this    
`<td ng-switch-default ng-bind="$parent.doorsize">@{{selectedSizeSwitch}}, @{{selectedStandardSize.label}}</td>`  

doesn't solve the problem  

what I expect is to get calculated value  
`{{selectedSizeSwitch}}, {{selectedStandardSize.label}}`  inside variable doorsize
and then to send `$scope.doorsize` in JSON array

Comment: when you use `ng-bind` it will replace the text inside the element with the value of the variable in the attribute `ng-bind` i.e `<b ng-bind="val">123</b>` will output `val`  and not `123`

Comment: so using `<td ng-switch-default ng-bind="$parent.doorsize">@{{selectedSizeSwitch}}, @{{selectedStandardSize.label}}</td>` will show the value of `$parent.doorsize`

Comment: any calculations you are doing, you need to do them in your javascript code not in your markup , `ng-model` is a way of using `two-binding` which means i can give an input element a `ng-model` variable and when i change the input`s value if will change the value of the model

Comment: `ng-bind` is a `one-way` bind, you can't change the value of the variable through the dom, it only calculates it and outputs it to the dom on every digest cycle

Comment: I am trying to do calculations in my script, but it doesn't work
    
`if ($scope.selectedSizeSwitch == $scope.sizeswitch[0].label) {$scope.doorsize = $scope.selectedSizeSwitch + ', ' + $scope.selectedStandardSize.label;
              } else {
                $scope.doorsize = $scope.selectedSizeSwitch + ', ' + $scope.DoorSizeB + 'x' + $scope.DoorSizeH;
              }    `

This code just give me initial value of `selectedSizeSwitch` and `selectedStandardSize.label`.
The value of `doorsize` is not changing together with changing `selectedStandardSize` in my form.